# Django Rest How do I call objects that are under my reference object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I cannot call the movies under a Director. I want to make a page where you click the name of the director and it will show the list of movies that are directed by the director. What shown below is the codes for models, serializers, and views.

```
models.py

class Director(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstname, self.lastname)


class Product(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    director = models.ForeignKey(Director, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
serializers.py

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    director = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class DirectorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Director
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
views.py

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getDirector(request):
    director = Director.objects.all()
    serializer = DirectorSerializer(director, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I already tried what is shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
views.py

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProductsByDirector(request, director_pk):
    products = Product.objects.filter(director_id=director_pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note: you don't need to add "_id" field in your models since it's automatically added.

Comment: Im using React for my front end so I think _id is required? Correct me if im wrong tho.